# Android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Tags: android, json, ip

Im using Java connect with MySQL and Json will send data to android, When I send data from Java to json by URL address:

```
http://192.168.1.221:9999/rentalcar_service/category/getAllManufacturer
```

everything's fine, but when I parse data in Android I received an error result following as:

```
private static final String URL_MANUFACTURERS = "http://192.168.1.221:9999/rentalcar_service/category/getAllManufacturer";
```

Logcat:

```
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed:    ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:223)
W/System.err:   ... 25 more
I/MemoryCache: cache size=0 length=4
W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 9999) after 30000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:234)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:171)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
```

(192.168.1.221) IP address is my PC, if I change from 192.168.1.221 to localhost, I still receive same error.

How to fix this problem? Thank so much !

Comment: Connection refused means the server wouldn't accept your connection.  The problem is going to be in your network setup or your server.  Most likely its a firewall in your wifi router.

Comment: Yes, I got your explain but current I just test on local machine

Comment: So you mean you have an emulator on the same machine as the server?  In that case, remember that the emulator is not localhost, you have to use the ip address of the PC.  And double check firewalls anyway, since you aren't localhost it will go over the network.

Comment: Right you are ! it can not be localhost address, I changed by my IP and its worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ECONNREFUSED means that the connection was attempted and the remote host port is not listening.
Hence this can be caused because of:

Is it a valid IP? check using ifconfig or ipconfig.
You can try pinging the server.

Details regarding the error can be understood from here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/jb-mr2-release/luni/src/main/java/libcore/io/ErrnoException.java
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/system/ErrnoException.html

Comment: thank so much ! I change localhost by my IP PC and updated URL in db and its worked ! thanks for your links

Comment: What about when a remote host is rebooted?  Wouldn't that cause a ECONNREFUSED

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access a mock local server (i.e. localhost) it won't work, because android runs on a separate environment (a device, or emulator), i.e. it has a different localhost than your development machine... you have to publish your server somewhere online.

If you just want a JSON in a REST api, you can use [My-Json-Server](https://my-json-server.typicode.com/).

Answer (score 0):

In my case: I changed to another wifi connection , and solved it. Because on my browser the link was opening.