# Android - Google Calendar - Network error

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I followed the instruction as given https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android for understanding how google calendar API works.

However I am always getting Error as

```
E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() -> NETWORK_ERROR. Account: <ELLIDED:1752607581>, App: com.pravasah.experimetforworldcalendar, Service: oauth2: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
[GetToken] GetToken failed with status code: NetworkError
```

Not able to find the exact issue.. All other apps requiring network are working fine.. only this app giving network error.

Kindly help

[Edit]
To be specific, error is connection refused by google server.
I have enabled the calendar API for app, generated client ID also, but I feel this error is before checking for any permission.
As I understand for debug app SHA1 generated is always same, so I have enabled oAuth2.0 client only for one app with same name.

When exactly google server refuse connection?

Comment: Have you add Internet permission in manifest ?

Comment: Yes... I have cross checked that  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>

Comment: Is your device connected with internet properly ?

Comment: Yes as I said, all my other internet dependent apps are working fine..

Comment: I found in this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41530816/) that ECONNREFUSED means that the client's connection request reached a host, but the host refused to allow the client to connect, as nothing is listening on the port requested. So this involves a IP issue. For more information check this [ErrnoException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/system/ErrnoException.html) that you are receiving.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. But in android the API's are so simple that we don't select any IP address or port. Libraries are provided for usage, all the connections and all are taken care by Google Calendar API's